# How to infinitely run a batch file in Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a batch file that starts a script in a directory, and then restarts that script every hour. (I am using pm2) I want this to happening continuously and need the help of some kind of loop. How will I get this to work?

```
REM cd to directory here
pm2 start script.js
timeout /T 3600
pm2 restart script.js
```

This is how my code looks right now. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Windows has a Task Scheduler, whereby you can create a task to run on a particular schedule.

Answer (score 1):

This concept can be accomplished using the GOTO command which allows you to go to a point in the script identified by a :label you use in the script.

```
pm2 start script.js
:LOOP
timeout /T 3600
pm2 restart script.js
GOTO LOOP
```